# Pandas dataframe group by column and add rest of column to named dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
category    week    sales
xyz         w1      22
xyz         w2      24
abc         w1      44
abc         w2      46
```

I am trying to convert this to a dict in the following format:

**DesiredResult**

```
{
  series: [
    {
      name: "xyz",
      data: [{
        x: 'W1',
        y: 22
      }, {
        x: 'W2',
        y: 24
      }]
    },
    {
      name: "abc",
      data: [{
        x: 'W1',
        y: 44
      }, {
        x: 'W2',
        y: 46
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following:

**Option 1:**

```
cate=df['category'].unique()
data=[]
for i in cate:
        ndf=df[df['category'] == i]
        ndf = ndf[['week','sales']]
        data.append({'name':i})
        for index,rows in ndf.iterrows():
                data.append({'data': [{'x':rows['week'],'y':rows['sales']}]})
```

**Option 2:**

```
for i in cate:
        ndf=d6[d6['category'] == i]
        ndf = ndf[['week','sales']]
        for index,rows in ndf.iterrows():
                data.append({'name':i,'data': [{'x':rows['week'],'y':rows['sales']}]})
```

The second one is the closest to what I need though I get the category tag attached with every named row.  How do I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {"series": []}
for i, g in df.groupby("category"):
    out["series"].append({"name": i, "data": []})
    for w, s in zip(g["week"], g["sales"]):
        out["series"][-1]["data"].append({"x": w, "y": s})

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "series": [
        {"name": "abc", "data": [{"x": "w1", "y": 44}, {"x": "w2", "y": 46}]},
        {"name": "xyz", "data": [{"x": "w1", "y": 22}, {"x": "w2", "y": 24}]},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you...works perfectly.....I never knew that we could do a group by on a iteration...Many thanks again.